# Python で tuple index out of range というエラーが出る

Tags: python, python3

Pythonでrandom関数を使ったじゃんけんプログラムを作っています。
その中で今までの勝ち負け引き分けのそれぞれ合計を出す部分が

```
Index Error : Taple index out of range
```

というエラーを出していてその解決法が分かりません。

どなたかご指導お願いします。

```
# じゃんけんゲーム
import random

hand = ["グー", "チョキ", "パー", "ゲーム終了"]

win = 0
lose = 0
draw = 0
time = 0

print("===じゃんけんしましょう===")

while True:

    com = random.randint(0,2)
    for i, desc in enumerate(hand):
        print(i, ":", desc)
    you  = int(input("出す手を数値で入力: "))

    time += 1                       # 試行回数

    if you == 3: break
    if you < 0 or you > 2:
        print("0から3の間で入力してね")
        continue

    print("---")
    print("自分 : ", hand[you])
    print("相手 : ", hand[com])
    input("---")

    j = (you - com + 3) % 3
    if j == 0:
        print("あいこ")
        draw += 1               # 引き分けた回数
    elif j == 1:
        print("負け...")
        lose += 1               # 負けた回数
    elif j == 2:
        print("勝ち!!!")
        win += 1                # 勝った回数
    input("---")

    rate = win / time
    print("現在の勝率 : ", rate)     # 勝率
    s = win, "勝", lose, "敗", draw, "分"       #内訳。ここはエラーなし
    print(s)
    s2 = "{1}勝ち{2}負け{3}分け".format(win, lose, draw) # Tuple index out of range と出る
    print(s2)
    input("---")
```

Comment: おなじ処理がありますが、比較というかエラーの出ないほうが私のやろうと思っていることです。わかりづらくてすみません。

Comment: index は `1` ではなく `0` から始まります。。。

Comment: 投稿に含まれるソースコードや、整形済みのテキストは[選択した上で `{}` ボタンをクリック](http://meta.ja.stackoverflow.com/a/2069/3054)して整形済みブロックにできます。インデントが保持され、`<` などの文字もそのまま使えるようになります。次回、必要になれば試してみて下さい。

Comment: metropolisさん、ありがとうございます！基本的なところを見落としていました。。。教えていただき感謝です。

Comment: mjyさん、ご指導ありがとうございます！次回からそのようにしてみます。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"{1}勝ち{2}負け{3}分け"ではなく、"{0}勝ち{1}負け{2}分け"とすればうまくいきます。
0オリジンで、タプルとしては3つしか与えていないのに、3つまりは4番目の値を入れようとして、その値が見つからないという意味です。
win:0番目
lose: 1番目
draw: 2番目

試しに、

```
>>> "{1}勝ち{2}負け{3}分け".format(1,2,3)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: tuple index out of range
>>> "{0}勝ち{1}負け{2}分け".format(1,2,3)
'1勝ち2負け3分け'
>>>
```

正しく動作するようになります。

Comment: あとわいとさん、ありがとうございます！無事解決いたしました。